# 3 killing errors: NoApiKeys, MissingKeyMapError, multiple Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3, google-api

2 days ago I migrated local site to live. 
Maps were working fine until yesterday night when 3 senseless erros came up.
I made no additional changes to maps nor anything API related.

This is what shows on my site console:

```
query-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
js:96 You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
$g @ js:96
(anonymous) @ js:131
google.maps.Load @ js:18
(anonymous) @ js:131
(anonymous) @ js:132
util.js:219 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
tB.j @ util.js:219
(anonymous) @ js:131
(anonymous) @ js:53
(anonymous) @ js:50
(anonymous) @ js:53
_.G @ js:52
(anonymous) @ js:53
_.v @ js:32
Xc @ js:53
(anonymous) @ js:131
js:35 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
_.rb @ js:35
(anonymous) @ common.js:50
(anonymous) @ common.js:195
c @ common.js:45
(anonymous) @ maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2F&callback=_xdc_._qm32vw&token=40357:1
```

I always generate API with KEY and exact same API is working properly on localsite while showing these errors:

```
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
js:96 You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
$g @ js:96
util.js:219 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
tB.j @ util.js:219
util.js:219 Google Maps API warning: InvalidVersion https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-version
tB.j @ util.js:219
```

Invalid Version error also was showing but after i restricted acces for key to HTTP resquest only its gone now.

Script and version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;key=AIzaSyDuZqGZbyrKc6qxeXhIcjIO3iGgqUzBjyM&amp;ver=4.12.1"></script>
```

I really dont know how to diagnose this.

Small update, map works properly when site was migrated form live to local.
The only JS error that appears is NoApiKeys

Comment: _You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors._

Please fix this first, check again and edit question.

Comment: you script is loading fine. but the multiple loading of a google script may cause this problem. Please fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

All these 3 errors are connected to each other. But the major issue was multiple map script running on my site.
 One that was empty caused the problems. I forgot that my mega menu had google map script that I didn't use. After removing it all 3 errors are gone.